# Adding the numbers from a string list

Tags: python, string, list, average

I open a list into my script and the search for matches to '2011' and print the '2011' strings using the following code

```
for row in dL:
    if "2011" in row:
        print row
```

and get the following output

```
['2011', 'randome', '6200']
['2011', 'marks', '6020']
['2011', 'man', '6430']
['2011', 'is', '6040']
['2011', 'good', '6230']
```

what I am trying to do is get all the values from the 3rd column and sum them to get the result 30920 and then calculate and print the average which is 6184. So far I have the following code.

```
   total = int(row[2])
   total2 = sum(total)
   print total2
```

however I get the following error

```
total2 = sum(total)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can I fix this error and create the total and averages??

Comment: Note: when you say 'row[2]' you mean *'the third column'* ;-) Not *'third row'*

Comment: Also if you're doing any non-trivial data-mungeing, learn pandas package, it makes stuff like this easy.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the sum of all the lists, not from one specifically (as you have tried).

Use a [`list comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of a for-loop:

```
total2 = sum(int(i[2]) for i in dL if '2011' in i)
```

To get the average:

```
average = total2 / float(len([int(i[2]) for i in dL if '2011' in i])) # In python 3, the float() is not needed
```

A list comprehension is a quick way to make a list. Take for example this:

```
result = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    result.append(i**2)
```

Result will contain:

```
[1, 4, 9]
```

However, this can be shortened to a list comprehension:

```
[i**2 for i in range(1,4)]
```

Which returns the same thing.

The reason for when I call `sum()` and I don't put in brackets around the comprehension is because I don't need to. Python interprets this as a *generator expression*. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/231855#231855)

Comment: Hi Hadiro ive replaced my total section of the code with your section however i get the following error.    total2 = sum(i[2] for i in dL if '2011' in i)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' would you know why that is??

Comment: @user2603519 I just fixed that as you commented :)

Comment: Thanks this works beautifully. If im trying to calculate the average how would i do so by using len of list?? But its not really a list??

Comment: Haidro. I am trying to use this code you have supplied in a loop but I am getting a value  division error. Can you help with this?? Do I need to make a new question??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33842/discussion-between-haidro-and-user2603519)

Comment: @user2603519 Make sure you're not dividing by zero.

Answer (score 0):

`total` should be a `list`.

```
total = [int(row[2]) for row in dL if '2011' in row]    # totals in a list
total2=sum(total)                                       # total of totals. :P
print total2                                            # print total
average = total2/len(total)                             # get average
print average                                           # print average
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want to get average also, accordinly you have to take length of filtered list also.
you can modify any of the above code accordingly, I will go with @haidro's answer.

```
l = [int(i[2]) for i in dL if '2011' in i]   #to get filtered list
total2 = sum(l)      #total of list elemnents
avg = total2/len(l)   #average of list elements
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks for correcting me... its if, not is... :)